# To find the value of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ and $w$ are two non zero complex numbers such that $|zw| =1$ and $\arg z - \arg w = \pi/2$ then conjugate of $(zw)$ =?

Comment: Does "(z*w)" = $zw$ or $\bar z w$ or perhaps something else?

Comment: It is  (zw) bar [ whole bar]

Comment: You mean as in $\overline{zw}$?

Comment: yes it is conjugate of whole thing

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Write $z$ and $w$ in polar form,
$$z=re^{i\alpha}\quad\hbox{and}\quad w=se^{i\beta}\ .$$
Then

- in terms of $r,s$ we have $|zw|=\cdots$
- in terms of $\alpha,\beta$ we have ${\rm Arg}(z)-{\rm Arg}(w)=\cdots$
- and so $\overline{zw}=\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

Let, $$z=|z|e^{i\arg z},\quad w=|w|e^{i\arg w}$$ Hence, $\overline{zw}=|zw|e^{-i(\arg z +\arg w)}=e^{-i(\pi/2+2\arg w)}=-ie^{-i2\arg w}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please elaborate !

Comment: but the answer options are 1 , -1 , -i , i

Comment: Then the question must be asking to find $z\bar{w}$. Just evaluate this the same way I did in my answer, you'll see the answer will be $-i$.